# Blank subscribers view in nexus 7 and Galaxy S3 (Opentok Face 2 Face Live Video chat)

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera, media, opentok

I am testing Opentok HelloWorld application(https://github.com/opentok/Android-Hello-World) for face 2 face live video streaming. I have tested in Nexus 7 and Samsung Galaxy S3. In both devices I am able to see only publisher view but not able to see subscribers view.

In Logcat I got following exception:

```
W/System.err(14796): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
I/opentok-rtsp(14796): rstp client channel closed. disconnecting.
```

For creating keys, I have created Project A in https://dashboard.tokbox.com, 
1. Enabled Peer 2 Peer connection and created session id from there
2. Created token id from session id.
3. copied that Project A api key, session id, token in to the code.

I have installed this same app in above two devices.

```
05-08 18:05:48.908: D/dalvikvm(14796): GC_CONCURRENT freed 565K, 9% free 7900K/8632K, paused 6ms+3ms, total 36ms
05-08 18:05:48.908: D/dalvikvm(14796): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
05-08 18:05:48.928: D/dalvikvm(14796): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 128K, 7% free 8110K/8632K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-08 18:05:48.948: D/dalvikvm(14796): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 293K, 8% free 8127K/8772K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-08 18:05:48.958: I/opentok-signal(14796): messagingServers count:1
05-08 18:05:48.958: I/opentok-signal(14796): Connecting to oms504-nyc.tokbox.com:5560
05-08 18:05:49.258: I/opentok-signal(14796): Rumor is now connected to null
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): WebSocketServer RumorClient connected
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): Client sending message: Message [
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 3; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): params :  key = uniqueId value = 0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4,  key = notifyDisconnectAddress value = oms504-nyc.tokbox.com; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): data 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): Client sending message: Message [
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 0; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :  0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): params ; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): data 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:49.258: I/opentok-signal(14796): connectToSession [2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-]
05-08 18:05:49.258: I/opentok-signal(14796): Subscribing to address [0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4]
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): Client sending message: Message [
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 0; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :  0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): params ; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): data 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:49.258: I/opentok-signal(14796): Subscribing to address [2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-]
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): Client sending message: Message [
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 0; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :  2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): params ; 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): data 
05-08 18:05:49.258: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:49.308: D/dalvikvm(14796): GC_CONCURRENT freed 710K, 10% free 7930K/8792K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 41ms
05-08 18:05:49.308: D/dalvikvm(14796): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
05-08 18:05:49.338: V/opentok-signal(14796): {"data":{"uniqueId":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","credentials":{"GUID":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","latency":"0","supportsWebRTC":false,"connectionId":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","connectParams":{"data":null,"token":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0yODUzNDQ1MiZzZGtfdmVyc2lvbj10YnJ1YnktdGJyYi12MC45MS4yMDExLTAyLTE3JnNpZz05NDY2NmI4MTU1ZjNkMjg1ZjI0ZGI3NzI1YzY3YjJiNzY1ZTgwNWI0OnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJnNlc3Npb25faWQ9Ml9NWDR5T0RVek5EUTFNbjR4TWpjdU1DNHdMakYtVjJWa0lFMWhlU0F3T0NBd016b3pOVG93TnlCUVJGUWdNakF4TTM0d0xqVXdOalU0TWpGLSZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xMzY4MDA5MzE3Jm5vbmNlPTAuODkyMjcxNDUxMjQ3OTU0JmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTEzNjgwOTYyNjUmY29ubmVjdGlvbl9kYXRhPQ==","tokenPermissions":{"role":"moderator","connectionData":null,"apiKey":"28534452","sdkVersion":"STAGED"},"detectConnectionQuality":"0"},"data":null,"userid":"0","widgetId":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","partnerId":"28534452","localTimeOffset":"-8","role":"moderator","soAccessState":"2","fullname":""},"params":{"data":null,"token":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0yODUzNDQ1MiZzZGtfdmVyc2lvbj10YnJ1YnktdGJyYi12MC45MS4yMDExLTAyLTE3JnNpZz05NDY2NmI4MTU1ZjNkMjg1ZjI0ZGI3NzI1YzY3YjJiNzY1ZTgwNWI0OnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJnNlc3Npb25faWQ9Ml9NWDR5T0RVek5EUTFNbjR4TWpjdU1DNHdMakYtVjJWa0lFMWhlU0F3T0NBd016b3pOVG93TnlCUVJGUWdNakF4TTM0d0xqVXdOalU0TWpGLSZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xMzY4MDA5MzE3Jm5vbmNlPTAuODkyMjcxNDUxMjQ3OTU0JmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTEzNjgwOTYyNjUmY29ubmVjdGlvbl9kYXRhPQ==","tokenPermissions":{"role":"moderator","connectionData":null,"apiKey":"28534452","sdkVersion":"STAGED"},"detectConnectionQuality":"0"},"sessionId":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-","sessionProperties":{"app":"opentok/2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-","tcUrl":"rtmp://oms504-nyc.tokbox.com/2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-"},"type":7,"clientId":92453263},"id":"0","replyTo":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","type":5}
05-08 18:05:49.338: D/opentok-signal(14796): Client sending message: Message [
05-08 18:05:49.338: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 2; 
05-08 18:05:49.338: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :  oms504-nyc.tokbox.com; 
05-08 18:05:49.338: D/opentok-signal(14796): params ; 
05-08 18:05:49.338: D/opentok-signal(14796): data {"data":{"uniqueId":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","credentials":{"GUID":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","latency":"0","supportsWebRTC":false,"connectionId":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","connectParams":{"data":null,"token":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0yODUzNDQ1MiZzZGtfdmVyc2lvbj10YnJ1YnktdGJyYi12MC45MS4yMDExLTAyLTE3JnNpZz05NDY2NmI4MTU1ZjNkMjg1ZjI0ZGI3NzI1YzY3YjJiNzY1ZTgwNWI0OnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJnNlc3Npb25faWQ9Ml9NWDR5T0RVek5EUTFNbjR4TWpjdU1DNHdMakYtVjJWa0lFMWhlU0F3T0NBd016b3pOVG93TnlCUVJGUWdNakF4TTM0d0xqVXdOalU0TWpGLSZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xMzY4MDA5MzE3Jm5vbmNlPTAuODkyMjcxNDUxMjQ3OTU0JmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTEzNjgwOTYyNjUmY29ubmVjdGlvbl9kYXRhPQ==","tokenPermissions":{"role":"moderator","connectionData":null,"apiKey":"28534452","sdkVersion":"STAGED"},"detectConnectionQuality":"0"},"data":null,"userid":"0","widgetId":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","partnerId":"28534452","localTimeOffset":"-8","role":"moderator","soAccessState":"2","fullname":""},"params":{"data":null,"token":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0yODUzNDQ1MiZzZGtfdmVyc2lvbj10YnJ1YnktdGJyYi12MC45MS4yMDExLTAyLTE3JnNpZz05NDY2NmI4MTU1ZjNkMjg1ZjI0ZGI3NzI1YzY3YjJiNzY1ZTgwNWI0OnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJnNlc3Npb25faWQ9Ml9NWDR5T0RVek5EUTFNbjR4TWpjdU1DNHdMakYtVjJWa0lFMWhlU0F3T0NBd016b3pOVG93TnlCUVJGUWdNakF4TTM0d0xqVXdOalU0TWpGLSZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xMzY4MDA5MzE3Jm5vbmNlPTAuODkyMjcxNDUxMjQ3OTU0JmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTEzNjgwOTYyNjUmY29ubmVjdGlvbl9kYXRhPQ==","tokenPermissions":{"role":"moderator","connectionData":null,"apiKey":"28534452","sdkVersion":"STAGED"},"detectConnectionQuality":"0"},"sessionId":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-","sessionProperties":{"app":"opentok/2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-","tcUrl":"rtmp://oms504-nyc.tokbox.com/2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-"},"type":7,"clientId":92453263},"id":"0","replyTo":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","type":5}
05-08 18:05:49.338: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:49.358: D/dalvikvm(14796): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 10% free 7939K/8792K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 34ms
05-08 18:05:52.458: D/t*.o*.a*.m*.f*.c*.Prot*(14796): Processing a MESSAGE_RECEIVED for session 2
05-08 18:05:52.478: D/opentok-signal(14796): Received Message: Message [
05-08 18:05:52.478: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 2; 
05-08 18:05:52.478: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :  0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4; 
05-08 18:05:52.478: D/opentok-signal(14796): params ; 
05-08 18:05:52.478: D/opentok-signal(14796): data {"type":4,"id":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-_56887073","data":{"type":8,"connectSuccess":true,"sessionId":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-","_reason":"Connect Success"}}
05-08 18:05:52.478: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:52.498: D/t*.o*.a*.m*.f*.c*.Prot*(14796): Processing a MESSAGE_RECEIVED for session 1
05-08 18:05:52.498: D/opentok-signal(14796): Received Message: Message [
05-08 18:05:52.498: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 2; 
05-08 18:05:52.498: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :  2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-, 2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-/connections; 
05-08 18:05:52.498: D/opentok-signal(14796): params ; 
05-08 18:05:52.498: D/opentok-signal(14796): data {"type":4,"id":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-_56887073","data":{"type":3,"action":1,"objectKey":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-","key":"connections","value":{"connectionsCount":2,"currentConnection":"56887073"},"currentActionId":2,"replyExpected":true}}
05-08 18:05:52.498: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:52.528: D/opentok-signal(14796): WebSocket server received a 'ReplyMessage' message
05-08 18:05:52.548: D/opentok-signal(14796): WebSocket server received a 'ReplyMessage' message
05-08 18:05:52.548: I/opentok-signal(14796): getSessionState
05-08 18:05:52.668: D/opentok-signal(14796): Client sending message: Message [
05-08 18:05:52.668: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 2; 
05-08 18:05:52.668: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :  oms504-nyc.tokbox.com; 
05-08 18:05:52.668: D/opentok-signal(14796): params ; 
05-08 18:05:52.668: D/opentok-signal(14796): data {"data":{"actions":[{"value":null,"key":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-","replyExpected":true,"type":1,"action":0}],"from":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","type":0},"id":"1","replyTo":"0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4","type":5}
05-08 18:05:52.668: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:52.688: D/dalvikvm(14796): GC_CONCURRENT freed 479K, 10% free 7952K/8792K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 67ms
05-08 18:05:52.688: D/t*.o*.a*.m*.f*.c*.Prot*(14796): Processing a MESSAGE_RECEIVED for session 2
05-08 18:05:52.698: D/opentok-signal(14796): Received Message: Message [
05-08 18:05:52.698: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 2; 
05-08 18:05:52.698: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :  2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-, 2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-/connections; 
05-08 18:05:52.698: D/opentok-signal(14796): params ; 
05-08 18:05:52.698: D/opentok-signal(14796): data {"type":4,"id":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-_56887073","data":{"type":3,"action":1,"objectKey":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-","key":"connections","value":{"connectionsCount":2,"currentConnection":"56887073"},"currentActionId":2,"replyExpected":true}}
05-08 18:05:52.698: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:52.698: D/opentok-signal(14796): WebSocket server received a 'ReplyMessage' message
05-08 18:05:52.918: D/t*.o*.a*.m*.f*.c*.Prot*(14796): Processing a MESSAGE_RECEIVED for session 2
05-08 18:05:52.928: D/opentok-signal(14796): Received Message: Message [
05-08 18:05:52.928: D/opentok-signal(14796): type : 2; 
05-08 18:05:52.928: D/opentok-signal(14796): addressId :  0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4; 
05-08 18:05:52.928: D/opentok-signal(14796): params ; 
05-08 18:05:52.928: D/opentok-signal(14796): data {"type":4,"id":"1","data":{"value":{"connections":{"connectionsCount":2,"currentConnection":"56887073"},"actionId":2},"key":"2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-"}}
05-08 18:05:52.928: D/opentok-signal(14796): ];
05-08 18:05:52.928: D/opentok-signal(14796): WebSocket server received a 'ReplyMessage' message
05-08 18:05:52.958: D/jnispeex(14796): storing instance pointer 40BB4E00
05-08 18:05:53.058: I/OMXClient(14796): Using client-side OMX mux.
05-08 18:05:53.078: D/opentok-android-config(14796): found avc encoder OMX.Nvidia.h264.encoder supported color formats: 19, 2130708361, 
05-08 18:05:53.088: D/opentok-android-config(14796): supported camera formats: 842094169, 17, 
05-08 18:05:53.088: D/opentok-android-config(14796): dumping all configs
05-08 18:05:53.088: D/opentok-android-config(14796): cameraFormat:842094169 encoderFormat:19 encoderName:OMX.Nvidia.h264.encoder pixelTranslator:com.opentok.media.PixelTranslators$YV12ToYUV420PlanarTranslator
05-08 18:05:53.088: D/opentok-android-config(14796): cameraFormat:17 encoderFormat:19 encoderName:OMX.Nvidia.h264.encoder pixelTranslator:null
05-08 18:05:53.088: D/opentok-android-config(14796): cameraFormat:842094169 encoderFormat:2130708361 encoderName:OMX.Nvidia.h264.encoder pixelTranslator:null
05-08 18:05:53.088: D/opentok-android-config(14796): cameraFormat:17 encoderFormat:2130708361 encoderName:OMX.Nvidia.h264.encoder pixelTranslator:null
05-08 18:05:53.088: I/OMXClient(14796): Using client-side OMX mux.
05-08 18:05:53.098: D/opentok-android-config(14796): found avc encoder OMX.Nvidia.h264.encoder supported color formats: 19, 2130708361, 
05-08 18:05:53.098: D/opentok-android-config(14796): supported camera formats: 842094169, 17, 
05-08 18:05:53.108: D/opentok-android-config(14796): selecting configuration cameraFormat:842094169 encoderFormat:19 encoderName:OMX.Nvidia.h264.encoder pixelTranslator:com.opentok.media.PixelTranslators$YV12ToYUV420PlanarTranslator
05-08 18:05:53.108: I/OMXClient(14796): Using client-side OMX mux.
05-08 18:05:53.108: I/ACodec(14796): setupVideoEncoder succeeded
05-08 18:05:53.178: I/System.out(14796): parsing sps/pps
05-08 18:05:53.178: D/opentok-avc-enc(14796): parsing sps
05-08 18:05:53.178: D/opentok-avc-enc(14796): modifying sps
05-08 18:05:53.248: V/opentok-clientlogging(14796): sent client event : {guid=7432e95b-7bad-44b1-8e4b-57166750c642, partner_id=28534452, widget_type=Controller, session_id=2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-, widget_id=0356cac6-5b2b-495d-91be-5d14c0ece002, action=ComponentLoaded, payload=com.opentok.helloworld::17::1.0::Android OS::::20121210151536-android::mfr=asus,model=Nexus 7,prod=nakasi,dev=grouper,abi=armeabi-v7a::google::, payload_type=appId::systemVersion::appVersion::systemName::networkStatus::libOpentokVersion::deviceModel::carrierName::, connection_id=0d9b937a-0bf8-4293-8af9-9b7d378831d4}
05-08 18:05:53.438: V/opentok-rtsp(14796): OPTIONS request sent:
05-08 18:05:53.438: V/opentok-rtsp(14796): OPTIONS rtsp://oms504-nyc.tokbox.com:1935/opentok/2_MX4yODUzNDQ1Mn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1heSAwOCAwMzozNTowNyBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjUwNjU4MjF-/SimpleVideoConference/userStreams/1393039330 RTSP/1.0
05-08 18:05:53.438: V/opentok-rtsp(14796): Cseq: 1
05-08 18:05:53.438: V/opentok-rtsp(14796): Content-Length: 0
05-08 18:05:53.438: V/opentok-rtsp(14796): 
05-08 18:05:53.448: W/System.err(14796): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
05-08 18:05:53.458: W/System.err(14796):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
05-08 18:05:53.458: W/System.err(14796):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:528)
05-08 18:05:53.458: W/System.err(14796):    at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.readImpl(SocketChannelImpl.java:314)
05-08 18:05:53.468: W/System.err(14796):    at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:276)
05-08 18:05:53.468: W/System.err(14796):    at com.opentok.io.AsyncSelectionIOBus.readKey(AsyncSelectionIOBus.java:233)
05-08 18:05:53.468: W/System.err(14796):    at com.opentok.io.AsyncSelectionIOBus.processSelectionKey(AsyncSelectionIOBus.java:176)
05-08 18:05:53.468: W/System.err(14796):    at com.opentok.io.AsyncSelectionIOBus.run(AsyncSelectionIOBus.java:150)
05-08 18:05:53.468: W/System.err(14796):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
05-08 18:05:53.468: W/System.err(14796):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-08 18:05:53.468: W/System.err(14796):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-08 18:05:53.478: W/System.err(14796):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-08 18:05:53.478: W/System.err(14796):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-08 18:05:53.478: W/System.err(14796): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
05-08 18:05:53.478: W/System.err(14796):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
05-08 18:05:53.478: W/System.err(14796):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)
05-08 18:05:53.478: W/System.err(14796):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:159)
05-08 18:05:53.478: W/System.err(14796):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:525)
05-08 18:05:53.478: W/System.err(14796):    ... 10 more
05-08 18:05:53.488: I/System.out(14796): Purging Key java.nio.SelectionKeyImpl@415d19b8 (channel=java.nio.SocketChannelImpl@4154eb58)
05-08 18:05:53.488: I/opentok-rtsp(14796): rstp client channel closed. disconnecting.
```

Comment: Did you try this with a non peer-to-peer enabled session?

Answer (score 0):

I think the connection might have been broken because of firewall or Symmetric NAT, preventing the 2 routers from talking to each other. If you generate a non p2p sessionId you should be able to get it working.